# Abstract Class - How can I solve abstract class error?

Tags: abstract-class, magento2

While accessing magento 2 storefront I got following error. Pretty new to magento. Any help on that would be really helpful.

`Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock in /var/www/html/magento_1/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121`

I am using magento latest version 2.4.2-p1.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please check my answer and accept if useful for future users?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/AbstractBlock.php` is there?

And run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from command line.
If you still have this issue also try `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove below class from constructor of custom extension and need to add related block class for same place and then check it's work for you.

```
Magento\Wishlist\Block\AbstractBlock
```

It's hope work for you.